# ignore NaN in regression output in R

Tags: r, nan

I got some NaNs in for some standard errors in my multinomial regression output (nnet package, formula multinom(). Now I want R to ignore these NaNs , for example in replacing them as zero. I tried the following code

```
unstack(within(stack(z$standard.error), values[is.nan(values)] <- 0))
```

with z as the summary test result. But it doesn't work. 
Is there a way to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please read [the answer to this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) to learn what a reproducible example is and how to give one. And I don't think it is a good idea to ignore `NaN`s in regression output. It is an indication of overfitting and other problems.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Due to this I found my mistake and now there are no NaNs anymore.

Comment: Next time, you can still re-write your question and share the answer you found so it can benefit everybody.